# Change volume and turn on/off silent mode

Tags: ios, ios5, jailbreak

This is for a jailbreak tweak, so it doesn't matter that I need to use private frameworks.

How can you change the volume of the device and how can you turn off silent mode?

If there is an easier way to play a sound at a specific volume and will always play regardless of silent mode is on or off, this will actually be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the volume using the `VolumeControl` class:

```
static void setVolume(float volume) {
    VolumeControl *volumeControl = [VolumeControl sharedVolumeControl];
    [volumeControl setMediaVolume:volume];
}
```

I don't know how to toggle the silent switch yet.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this out, so no guarantees regarding it functioning properly ...

but just by looking at the dumped header, I would try this for turning silent mode on or off:

```objc
VolumeControl *volumeControl = [VolumeControl sharedVolumeControl];
[volumeControl toggleMute];
```

let me know if it works for you ...

Comment: Doesn't work, as it doesn't change the mode it just switches between setting the volume to 0 and back to what is was before.

Comment: @Tyilo, that sounds like exactly what I'd expect from a method named `toggleMute`.  What behavior are you looking for?  Have you [looked at this](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/21456-detect-wheather-phone-is-in-silent-mode-or-ring-mode.html) ... `AudioSessionSetProperty`?

Comment: If my iPhone is in silent mode, and I call the `toggleMute` method, I will still be in silent mode. I'm looking for how to do something like the `Ringer/Silent SBSettings Toggle` packages in Cydia,

Comment: @Tyilo,  have you tried running things like `otool -L Toggle.dylib` and `strings Toggle.dylib` on that toggle (under /var/mobile/Library/SBSettings/Toggles/*) to try to figure out how it accomplishes this?

Comment: I have already done this (with IDA Pro) and I think it is using `AVSystemController` from `Celestial` framework. However I don't understand how it does this.

Comment: @Tyilo, remember to post what you've tried, and learned, *in your question*.

Comment: This could be a round-about way but you could hook the actual volume function, and make it so that if a variable is true it returns like 1.0.